# Is "one moment... while on the other" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the following expression properly written, or does it need some improvement to make the right sense:

> One moment she was acting all calm and quiet, while on the other she started being outrageously loud and noisy.

I'm very eager to know the correct usage of "one moment... while on the other" like expression in a sentence. I could be mistakenly using it with the wrong set of words, so please help me rectify this.

Comment: I would expect something like "one moment ... and then the next".  As written, it feels like you're mixing in "on the one hand ... on the other hand".

Comment: Illogical. There is only one _next moment_ ('_the_ next'), but many _other moments_. And here, logic reinforces idiomaticity for once.